# How to Destroy a Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript: $('#img1').zoom();">Add Zoom Feature to the following picture.</a>
<a href="javascript: ***HOW***">Remove Zoom Feature</a>
<img  id="img1" src="1.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is how to deselect a jquery function called earlier on an object. The following function is given but its not working at all.

```
function destroyZoome(obj){
    if(obj.parent().hasClass('zm-wrap'))
    {
        obj.unwrap().next().remove();
    }
}
```

The following is the code for zoom.js or zoome-e.js as its named, I renamed the js filename and function name here for better understanding.

```
(function ($) {
    var zoome = {
        $currentImgWrap: null,
        $magnifier: null,
        $magnifierImg: null,
        $magnifierState: null,
        init: function () {
            zoome.$magnifier = $('<div id="zm-magnifier"><img style="position:relative;left:0;top:0;"/><span>1X</span></div>').appendTo('body');
            zoome.$magnifierImg = $('img', zoome.$magnifier);
            zoome.$magnifierState = $('span', zoome.$magnifier);
            $(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                if (zoome.$currentImgWrap) {
                    zoome.movemagnifier(e)
                }
            });
            zoome.$magnifier.mousewheel(function (e, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
                var info = zoome.$currentImgWrap.get(0).zoominfo;
                var op = deltaY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                var nextZoom = Math.round((info.currentZoom + info.zoomStep * op) * 10) / 10.0;
                if (nextZoom <= info.zoomRange[1] && nextZoom >= info.zoomRange[0]) {
                    info.currentZoom = nextZoom;
                    zoome.$magnifierImg.css({
                            left: -(e.pageX - info.coords.left) * info.currentZoom + info.magnifierSize[0] / 2,
                            top: -(e.pageY - info.coords.top) * info.currentZoom + info.magnifierSize[1] / 2,
                            width: info.imgSize.width * info.currentZoom,
                            height: info.imgSize.height * info.currentZoom
                        });
                    zoome.$magnifierState.text(info.currentZoom + 'X')
                }
                e.preventDefault()
            });
        },
        setup: function ($img, options, fn) {
            if ($img.parent().attr('id') != 'zm-magnifier') {
                var i_w, i_h, largeImg, $hover_layer;
                $img.wrap('<div class="zm-wrap"></div>');
                var $imgWrap = $img.parent();
                if (options.hoverEf == 'transparent') {
                    $hover_layer = $('<div class="zm-hover zm-trans"></div>').appendTo($imgWrap)
                } else {
                    $hover_layer = $img.clone().addClass('zm-hover').appendTo($imgWrap);
                    if (options.hoverEf == 'grayscale') {
                        fn.grayscale($hover_layer)
                    } else if (options.hoverEf == 'blur') {
                        if ($.browser.msie) {
                            $hover_layer.addClass("zm-blur")
                        } else {
                            fn.blur($hover_layer, 3)
                        }
                    }
                } if ($img.attr(options.largeImgAttr)) {
                    largeImg = $img.attr(options.largeImgAttr);
                    new Image().src = largeImg
                } else {
                    largeImg = $img.attr('src')
                }
                $imgWrap.get(0).zoominfo = {
                    defaultZoom: options.defaultZoom,
                    zoomStep: options.zoomStep,
                    zoomRange: options.zoomRange,
                    showZoomState: options.showZoomState,
                    borderSize: 3,
                    imgSize: null,
                    coords: null,
                    largeImg: null,
                    currentZoom: options.defaultZoom,
                    magnifierSize: options.magnifierSize
                };
                $imgWrap.bind('mouseover', function () {
                    zoome.$currentImgWrap = $(this);
                    var $img = $('img:first', this);
                    var info = $(this).get(0).zoominfo;
                    info.coords = {
                        left: $img.offset().left,
                        top: $img.offset().top,
                        right: $img.offset().left + $img.width(),
                        bottom: $img.offset().top + $img.height()
                    };
                    info.largeImg = $img.attr(options.largeImgAttr) ? $img.attr(options.largeImgAttr) : $img.attr('src');
                    info.imgSize = {
                        width: $img.width(),
                        height: $img.height()
                    };
                    $(this).get(0).zoominfo = info;
                    zoome.$magnifierImg.attr('src', info.largeImg).css({
                            width: info.currentZoom * info.imgSize.width,
                            height: info.currentZoom * info.imgSize.height
                        });
                    zoome.$magnifier.css({
                            width: info.magnifierSize[0],
                            height: info.magnifierSize[1]
                        }).fadeIn(300);
                    if (info.showZoomState) {
                        zoome.$magnifierState.text(info.currentZoom + 'X').show()
                    } else {
                        zoome.$magnifierState.hide()
                    }
                    $(this).find('.zm-hover').fadeIn(400)
                });
            }
        },
        movemagnifier: function (e) {
            var info = zoome.$currentImgWrap.get(0).zoominfo;
            if (e.pageX >= info.coords.left && e.pageX <= info.coords.right && e.pageY >= info.coords.top && e.pageY <= info.coords.bottom) {
                zoome.$magnifier.css({
                        left: e.pageX - info.magnifierSize[0] / 2 - info.borderSize,
                        top: e.pageY - info.magnifierSize[1] / 2 - info.borderSize
                    });
                zoome.$magnifierImg.css({
                        left: -(e.pageX - info.coords.left) * info.currentZoom + info.magnifierSize[0] / 2,
                        top: -(e.pageY - info.coords.top) * info.currentZoom + info.magnifierSize[1] / 2
                    })
            } else {
                zoome.$currentImgWrap.find('.zm-hover').fadeOut(300);
                zoome.$currentImgWrap = null;
                zoome.$magnifier.hide()
            }
        }
    };
    (function ($) {
        var fn = {
            img2Gray: function (img) {
                try {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                    for (var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++) {
                        for (var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++) {
                            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                            imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg
                        }
                    }
                    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
                    $(img).attr('src', canvas.toDataURL())
                } catch (err) {
                    alert('Canvas can not getImageData from local or corss domain image!')
                }
            },
            grayscale: function ($img) {
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $img.addClass("zm-gray")
                } else {
                    fn.img2Gray($img.get(0))
                }
            },
            blur: function ($img, radius) {
                function BlurStack() {
                    this.r = 0;
                    this.g = 0;
                    this.b = 0;
                    this.a = 0;
                    this.next = null
                }
                var mul_table = [512, 512, 456, 512, 328, 456, 335, 512, 405, 328, 271, 456, 388, 335, 292, 512, 454, 405, 364, 328, 298, 271, 496, 456, 420, 388, 360, 335, 312, 292, 273, 512, 482, 454, 428, 405, 383, 364, 345, 328, 312, 298, 284, 271, 259, 496, 475, 456, 437, 420, 404, 388, 374, 360, 347, 335, 323, 312, 302, 292, 282, 273, 265, 512, 497, 482, 468, 454, 441, 428, 417, 405, 394, 383, 373, 364, 354, 345, 337, 328, 320, 312, 305, 298, 291, 284, 278, 271, 265, 259, 507, 496, 485, 475, 465, 456, 446, 437, 428, 420, 412, 404, 396, 388, 381, 374, 367, 360, 354, 347, 341, 335, 329, 323, 318, 312, 307, 302, 297, 292, 287, 282, 278, 273, 269, 265, 261, 512, 505, 497, 489, 482, 475, 468, 461, 454, 447, 441, 435, 428, 422, 417, 411, 405, 399, 394, 389, 383, 378, 373, 368, 364, 359, 354, 350, 345, 341, 337, 332, 328, 324, 320, 316, 312, 309, 305, 301, 298, 294, 291, 287, 284, 281, 278, 274, 271, 268, 265, 262, 259, 257, 507, 501, 496, 491, 485, 480, 475, 470, 465, 460, 456, 451, 446, 442, 437, 433, 428, 424, 420, 416, 412, 408, 404, 400, 396, 392, 388, 385, 381, 377, 374, 370, 367, 363, 360, 357, 354, 350, 347, 344, 341, 338, 335, 332, 329, 326, 323, 320, 318, 315, 312, 310, 307, 304, 302, 299, 297, 294, 292, 289, 287, 285, 282, 280, 278, 275, 273, 271, 269, 267, 265, 263, 261, 259];
                var shg_table = [9, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24];
                try {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var width = canvas.width = $img.width();
                    var height = canvas.height = $img.height();
                    context.drawImage($img.get(0), 0, 0, width, height);
                    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    var pixels = imageData.data;
                    var x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw, r_sum, g_sum, b_sum, r_out_sum, g_out_sum, b_out_sum, r_in_sum, g_in_sum, b_in_sum, pr, pg, pb, rbs;
                    var div = radius + radius + 1;
                    var w4 = width << 2;
                    var widthMinus1 = width - 1;
                    var heightMinus1 = height - 1;
                    var radiusPlus1 = radius + 1;
                    var sumFactor = radiusPlus1 * (radiusPlus1 + 1) / 2;
                    var stackStart = new BlurStack();
                    var stack = stackStart;
                    for (i = 1; i < div; i++) {
                        stack = stack.next = new BlurStack();
                        if (i == radiusPlus1) var stackEnd = stack
                    }
                    stack.next = stackStart;
                    var stackIn = null;
                    var stackOut = null;
                    yw = yi = 0;
                    var mul_sum = mul_table[radius];
                    var shg_sum = shg_table[radius];
                    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                        r_in_sum = g_in_sum = b_in_sum = r_sum = g_sum = b_sum = 0;
                        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pr = pixels[yi]);
                        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pg = pixels[yi + 1]);
                        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pb = pixels[yi + 2]);
                        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
                        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
                        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
                        stack = stackStart;
                        for (i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++) {
                            stack.r = pr;
                            stack.g = pg;
                            stack.b = pb;
                            stack = stack.next
                        }
                        for (i = 1; i < radiusPlus1; i++) {
                            p = yi + ((widthMinus1 < i ? widthMinus1 : i) << 2);
                            r_sum += (stack.r = (pr = pixels[p])) * (rbs = radiusPlus1 - i);
                            g_sum += (stack.g = (pg = pixels[p + 1])) * rbs;
                            b_sum += (stack.b = (pb = pixels[p + 2])) * rbs;
                            r_in_sum += pr;
                            g_in_sum += pg;
                            b_in_sum += pb;
                            stack = stack.next
                        }
                        stackIn = stackStart;
                        stackOut = stackEnd;
                        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                            pixels[yi] = (r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                            pixels[yi + 1] = (g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                            pixels[yi + 2] = (b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
                            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
                            b_sum -= b_out_sum;
                            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
                            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
                            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
                            p = (yw + ((p = x + radius + 1) < widthMinus1 ? p : widthMinus1)) << 2;
                            r_in_sum += (stackIn.r = pixels[p]);
                            g_in_sum += (stackIn.g = pixels[p + 1]);
                            b_in_sum += (stackIn.b = pixels[p + 2]);
                            r_sum += r_in_sum;
                            g_sum += g_in_sum;
                            b_sum += b_in_sum;
                            stackIn = stackIn.next;
                            r_out_sum += (pr = stackOut.r);
                            g_out_sum += (pg = stackOut.g);
                            b_out_sum += (pb = stackOut.b);
                            r_in_sum -= pr;
                            g_in_sum -= pg;
                            b_in_sum -= pb;
                            stackOut = stackOut.next;
                            yi += 4
                        }
                        yw += width
                    }
                    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                        g_in_sum = b_in_sum = r_in_sum = g_sum = b_sum = r_sum = 0;
                        yi = x << 2;
                        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pr = pixels[yi]);
                        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pg = pixels[yi + 1]);
                        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * (pb = pixels[yi + 2]);
                        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
                        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
                        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
                        stack = stackStart;
                        for (i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++) {
                            stack.r = pr;
                            stack.g = pg;
                            stack.b = pb;
                            stack = stack.next
                        }
                        yp = width;
                        for (i = 1; i <= radius; i++) {
                            yi = (yp + x) << 2;
                            r_sum += (stack.r = (pr = pixels[yi])) * (rbs = radiusPlus1 - i);
                            g_sum += (stack.g = (pg = pixels[yi + 1])) * rbs;
                            b_sum += (stack.b = (pb = pixels[yi + 2])) * rbs;
                            r_in_sum += pr;
                            g_in_sum += pg;
                            b_in_sum += pb;
                            stack = stack.next;
                            if (i < heightMinus1) {
                                yp += width
                            }
                        }
                        yi = x;
                        stackIn = stackStart;
                        stackOut = stackEnd;
                        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                            p = yi << 2;
                            pixels[p] = (r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                            pixels[p + 1] = (g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                            pixels[p + 2] = (b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
                            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
                            b_sum -= b_out_sum;
                            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
                            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
                            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
                            p = (x + (((p = y + radiusPlus1) < heightMinus1 ? p : heightMinus1) * width)) << 2;
                            r_sum += (r_in_sum += (stackIn.r = pixels[p]));
                            g_sum += (g_in_sum += (stackIn.g = pixels[p + 1]));
                            b_sum += (b_in_sum += (stackIn.b = pixels[p + 2]));
                            stackIn = stackIn.next;
                            r_out_sum += (pr = stackOut.r);
                            g_out_sum += (pg = stackOut.g);
                            b_out_sum += (pb = stackOut.b);
                            r_in_sum -= pr;
                            g_in_sum -= pg;
                            b_in_sum -= pb;
                            stackOut = stackOut.next;
                            yi += width
                        }
                    }
                    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
                    $img.attr('src', canvas.toDataURL())
                } catch (err) {
                    alert('Canvas can not getImageData from local or corss domain image!')
                }
            }
        };
        $.fn.zoome = function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                    defaultZoom: 2,
                    largeImgAttr: 'rel',
                    zoomRange: [1, 10],
                    zoomStep: 1,
                    showZoomState: false,
                    magnifierSize: [140, 140],
                    borderSize: 3,
                    hoverEf: 'normal'
                }, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                    if (this.tagName != "IMG") return true;
                    if ($(this).attr("src") && $.trim($(this).attr("src")) != "") {
                        if (this.complete) {
                            zoome.setup($(this), settings, fn)
                        } else {
                            $(this).one('load', function () {
                                    zoome.setup($(this), settings, fn)
                                })
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    })(jQuery);
    (function ($) {
        var types = ['DOMMouseScroll', 'mousewheel'];
        if ($.event.fixHooks) {
            for (var i = types.length; i;) {
                $.event.fixHooks[types[--i]] = $.event.mouseHooks
            }
        }
        $.event.special.mousewheel = {
            setup: function () {
                if (this.addEventListener) {
                    for (var i = types.length; i;) {
                        this.addEventListener(types[--i], handler, false)
                    }
                } else {
                    this.onmousewheel = handler
                }
            },
            teardown: function () {
                if (this.removeEventListener) {
                    for (var i = types.length; i;) {
                        this.removeEventListener(types[--i], handler, false)
                    }
                } else {
                    this.onmousewheel = null
                }
            }
        };
        $.fn.extend({
                mousewheel: function (fn) {
                    return fn ? this.bind("mousewheel", fn) : this.trigger("mousewheel")
                },
                unmousewheel: function (fn) {
                    return this.unbind("mousewheel", fn)
                }
            });

        function handler(event) {
            var orgEvent = event || window.event,
                args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
                delta = 0,
                returnValue = true,
                deltaX = 0,
                deltaY = 0;
            event = $.event.fix(orgEvent);
            event.type = "mousewheel";
            if (orgEvent.wheelDelta) {
                delta = orgEvent.wheelDelta / 120
            }
            if (orgEvent.detail) {
                delta = -orgEvent.detail / 3
            }
            deltaY = delta;
            if (orgEvent.axis !== undefined && orgEvent.axis === orgEvent.HORIZONTAL_AXIS) {
                deltaY = 0;
                deltaX = -1 * delta
            }
            if (orgEvent.wheelDeltaY !== undefined) {
                deltaY = orgEvent.wheelDeltaY / 120
            }
            if (orgEvent.wheelDeltaX !== undefined) {
                deltaX = -1 * orgEvent.wheelDeltaX / 120
            }
            args.unshift(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);
            return ($.event.dispatch || $.event.handle).apply(this, args)
        }
    })(jQuery);
    $(function () {
        zoome.init();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: if you're using jQuery, you really shouldn't be having code embedded in your HTML like that.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you want to destroy the function, but to reverse its effects, right?

Comment: since `.zoom()` is (presumably) a method in zoom.js, the answer to how to reverse it's effects would also be in zoom.js.

Comment: @Asim, show us where the `zoom.js` file came from and we can help you. We don't know what it does or how it works, so we don't know how to destroy or deselect it.

Comment: Now why have you given us a version of your code that's been through one of those so-called "packers"?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for only once

```
$("#id").one("click", function() {
 $('#img1').zoom();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <a id="first" href="javascript: $('#img1').zoom();">Add Zoom Feature to the following picture.</a>
<a href="javascript:$('#first').attr('href', '');">Remove Zoom Feature</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. Its solved now. I was using an older version of jquery.